# MySql: best practice for message table with over 2 millions rows

Tags: mysql

In my database (MySql 5.7.32-35) I have a message table (type InnoDB) with over 2 million rows containing user message conversations.

```
FIELD       TYPE        NULL    KEY DEFAULT EXTRA
----------- ----------- ------- --- ------- --------------
id          int(11)     NO      PRI NULL    auto_increment  
messagedate datetime    NO          NULL
messagefrom int(11)     NO      MUL NULL
messageto   int(11)     NO      MUL NULL
messagetext text        NO          NULL
deletedfrom int(11)     NO          0       
deletedto   int(11)     NO          0       
ack         tinyint(1)  NO          0
```

Whenever a user writes a message (a simple INSERT INTO TABLE) depending on how many users are posting or viewing conversations, the site freezes for seconds (not very nice) .. maybe some table locks.
How can avoid this?

Any suggestion on best practice to manage user conversations? I mean .. how do chat programs handle thousands of user conversations?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are many things that might account for poor performance. With no schema, queries, or sample data, anything we suggest is guesswork.

Comment: I added table schema.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)